# Background Video isnt centralizing in bootstrap cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

Ok I am stuck with this problem.

Below is a code snippet with bootstrap CSS. its a small responsive DIV block, in which I want to show a video in the background, centralized, and scaling as much space as narrowly possible, whilst still covering the whole cell.

The Video and Text is placed inside a cell, the video first has a container, in which there is wrapper, then the video element.

```
....
<div class="col-md-2" style="height: 200px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px;">
 <div style="position:relative; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0; margin: auto; ">
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: -100; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0;">
   <video style=" min-height: 100%; min-width:100%; overflow: hidden;" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
    <source src="images/motiondesign.mp4" type="video/mp4">Video Not Supported</source>
   </video>
  </div>

  <div class="block yellow" style="background:none;">
   <h1>Motion Design</h1><p>Temp descriptive Text</p><p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Action</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
....
```

Although the video does appear nicely within its borders, *the video does not appear central atm, neither vertically nor horizontally*.

I have left the styling inline for now (sorry for the slight mess), which I will put into classes and CSS files after solving this problem...

**EDIT:** The problem is not if the div.col-md-2 is badly placing itself in the grid system. The problem that I cant solve, is that the Video *within* the background of the div.col-md-2 is not centralizing. I only see the left-hand side of the video. I want to see the center of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap works on 12 column grid system relative to your container size, your `col-md-2` is taking up the first two of those columns hence why it's not centering as you like. To center how you have it set up I would suggest you apply an `col-md-offset-*` to position your video more to your liking.

I stripped all the inline CSS and other divs to show you a centered version of your video [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/meXoKq/).

Read more about the Bootstrap Grid System in the [Bootstrap API](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: You think that the problem is that the cell is not placing correctly within the grid system (this is not the problem). My problem is that the video *within* the div.col-md-2 is not centralizing in the background.

Comment: Not quite sure if you want your header and button inside the video but I reworked the CodePen above. Now it shows you how to center with bootstrap by using ``text-center`` and ``center-block`` classes. I axed your inline css because it was hard to read.